# Find first image from post content with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, post, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get the first image from each of my posts content. below code not works. But if I have more then one images then gives me an image but last image.

I really only want the first image.

```
function catch_that_image($post_content) {
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
return $first_img;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First, paste this function into your functions.php file.

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Once done, you can simply call the function within the loop to display the first image from the post:

```
<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

here is [link](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it/)

Comment: I have done same thing but still i got third image from content.

Comment: let me ask you did you tried to make the first image of the post content as a featured image? or you want to fetch it and want to show somewhere if yes where you tried to show it?

Comment: Also, did you tried to change the values in an array of  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];? and then tried to eco this.

Comment: I have custom post listing page and i want to show first image from post content in loop with post title. I have added custom image not media url.